# display input via array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three input boxes. Once the user has added data into the three input boxes they click a button that adds that data to the array. I want multiple people to be able to add data into the input boxes and then to click the button to add that data into the array. There will be another button on the page that allows the user to see all of the data within the array and that also tells them how many values are within the array. This is what I have so far although I'm sure most of it is incorrect as I've just started learning javascript. Can someone give me a hand? Much appreciated.

```js
var customerarray = [];

function displaydata() {
var customerName = document.getElementById('custName').value;
var customerID = document.getElementById('custID').value;
var AmountDue = document.getElementById('Amount').value;
var innerTemphtml = '';
for(var i=0;i<customerarray.length;i--) {
  innerTemphtml + = customerarray[i].customerName+ " " + customerarray[i].customerID+ " " + customerarray[i].AmountDue;

     }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=innerTemphtml ;
 }

function addtoarray() {
customerarray.push({customerName:document.getElementById('custName').value, 
customerID: document.getElementById('custID').value, 
AmountDue: docment.getElementById('Amount').value});
}
```

```html
<body>
<span>Customer Name: </span>
<input type="text" id=custName></input><br><br>
<span>Customer ID: </span>
<input type="text" id=CustID></input><br><br>
<span>Amount: </span>
<input type="text" id=Amount></input> <br><br>
<button onclick="displaydata()" class="button" type = "button">add to array</button>
<button onclick="addtoarray()" class="button" type = "button"> Display data</button>
<p id="output"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
var i = customerarray.length
while (i--) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = customerarray[i].custName + " " + customerarray[i].custID + " " + customerarray[i].Amount;

}
```

With this

```
var innerTemphtml = '';
for(var i=0;i<customerarray.length;i--) {
  innerTemphtml + = customerarray[i].customerName+ " " + customerarray[i].customerID+ " " + customerarray[i].AmountDue;

     }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=innerTemphtml ;
 }
```

Final Code after replacing

```
var customerarray = [];

function displaydata() {
  var innerTemphtml = ' ';
  for (var i = 0; i < customerarray.length; i++) {

    innerTemphtml += customerarray[i].customerName + " " + customerarray[i].customerID + " " + customerarray[i].AmountDue;
  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = innerTemphtml;

}

function addtoarray() {
  customerarray.push({
    customerName: document.getElementById('custName').value,
    customerID: document.getElementById('CustID').value,
    AmountDue: document.getElementById('Amount').value
  });
}
```

**Observations**:

- Infinite loop with `while`
- Properties used to construct object and used are different which will result in `undefined`

[**Try this working Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1jpgxKy1MZDfnrwANAXG?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I added your code but still cant seem to get it to work. I've added a snipper of my code above. Are you able to take a look again?

Comment: @Mithrandir there is case sensitivity issue with your element id,for example you declared it as "CustID" and calling as "custID" there its failing

Comment: Added snippet and modified code accordingly have a close look on it @Mithrandir

Comment: thanks for your help! one last question, is there a way I can get each input value to appear on a different line. For example: Karl - 881 - $10 to appear on one line and Sam -994 - $20 to appear on the line below?

Comment: nevermind I have figured it out myself, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @Mithrandir just append '<br>' tag it will work for Example: 
`innerTemphtml +='<br>'+ customerarray[i].customerName + " " + customerarray[i].customerID + " " + customerarray[i].AmountDue;`